# How to get duplicate boot output on tty and serial console with systemd

Tags: centos, systemd, tty, console, serial-console

In el6 with `console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200` in the kernel cmdline I would get sysvinit *and* kernel printk output in both the AWS system log and the instance screenshot.

Example showing both printk and sysvinit output:

```
NET: Registered protocol family 10
lo: Disabled Privacy Extensions
Bringing up loopback interface:  [  OK  ]
<..>
Starting sshd: [  OK  ]
Starting ntpd: [  OK  ]
Starting postfix: [  OK  ]
Starting crond: [  OK  ]
Starting atd: [  OK  ]
Starting consul: [  OK  ]
Starting oddjobd: [  OK  ]
Starting certmonger: [  OK  ]

CentOS release 6.10 (Final)
Kernel 2.6.32-754.35.1.el6.x86_64 on an x86_64

ip-1-2-3-4.ec2.internal login:
```

The output is all but identical in the instance screenshot.

In el7 and el8 (systemd) it seems whichever `console=` is last will get both kernel printk and systemd output. The other will just get the kernel printk. Is there a way to duplicate the behavior of el6? Neither the system log nor the screenshot will ever have stdin attached to them. I just need the same stdout/err if possible. I've been trying to see if `DefaultStandardOutput` and/or `LogTarget` (system.conf or user.conf) or maybe even `ForwardToConsole` (journald.conf) might be what I'm looking for, but the documentation on freedesktop.org is rather sparse for these options and I don't want to break the current journald logging.